# How to encode user credentials in angularjs 2/4/5 application and use in PHP

Tags: php, angular, jwt

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to create a login application with some security. I am using JWT token authentication on server side(php). 
When I pass http request to the server, I am using below code

```
    login(username: string, password: string) {
     const HEADER = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }) };
    return this.http.post<any>(this.loginPageUrl, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),HEADER)
        .map(user => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            if (user && user.token) {
                console.log(user.token);
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }

            return user;
        });
}
```

In this case, User credentials are easily visible in any browser under "XHR". like below

**Form Data**
view parsed
{"username":"dd","password":"dd"}

How do I hide/encode this data?

Comment: Why is it a problem? As long as you're using TLS/HTTPS to transmit the data securely to your API/server you should be good

Comment: Because I want to hide password and it should not be in plain text anywhere not even in database.

Comment: You see your credentials in plain text in your browser dev tools because the browser is showing you the http request before it is sent over the network. The request get's encrypted before it is sent over the network. So if someone is sniffing the network, they can intercept the packet but they won't be able to make sense of it. So what you have in angular is correct. As far as encrypting the password and storing it in your database, that is a totally different question.

Comment: Thanks for your support and explaination  @LLai
I understood.